# Javascript split string based on index

Tags: javascript, string

Am new to java script. I have a string variable like the following way

```
var linkedinid = R3kyEgkyJxlinkedin; // it may sometimes R3kyEgkyJxlinkedincompany
```

I have to split this string to get the id part only ie "R3kyEgkyJx"

What am planning to do is find index value linkedin or linkedincompany in the string and take the id part only. I tried the following code. Its getting result as expected. But am not sure is it the best way to do it. I don't know is any other better way around. Please guide me in right direction. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

```
var str = "R3kyEgkyJxlinkedin"; // R3kyEgkyJxlinkedincompany (sometimes string may contain linkedincompany)
var n = str.indexOf("linkedin");
if(n == -1) {

n = str.indexOf("linkedincompany");
 if(n == -1) {
     // no match found
    } else { 

     var id = id = str.slice(0,n);
    }

} else { 

 var id = str.slice(0,n);

}

console.log('linked in id', id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var str = "R3kyEgkyJxlinkedin",
    id = str.replace('linkedincompany', '').replace('linkedin', '');
```

Basically, just remove `"linkedincompany"` and `"linkedin"` from the string.

Or, even shorter:

```
id = str.replace(/linkedin(company)?/, '');
```

Or:

```
id = str.replace(/linkedin.*$/, '');
```

Comment: or `.replace(/linkedin.*$/,'')`

Answer (score 2):

You can find the index of "linkedin" and use substring from 0 to that index:

```
var linkedinid  = "R3kyEgkyJxlinkedin";
var id = linkedinid.substr(0, linkedinid.indexOf('linkedin') );
```

If there's no "linkedin" substring it will work as `s.substr(0, -1)` and then `id == ""`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of the value of the string to be removed:
like in the above case you wish to remove linkedin,whose size is 8,
you may also try:-

`var linkedinId = "R3kyEgkyJxlinkedin";
linkedinId = linkedinId.slice(0,-8);  //or linkedinId.slice(0,-15); in case of R3kyEgkyJxlinkedincompany`